# Java calling dll String return type method

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I am trying to call the function inside the DLL file through JAVA application.
I have found this source http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/ and everything working like a charm.

But then, I would like to have some modification on the DLL file which I want the function to return String instead of char from the source.

Here is my java code.

```
public class Main {
   public interface simpleDLL extends Library {
     simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary("simpleDLL", simpleDLL.class);
     int giveIntGetInt(int a);               // int giveIntGetInt(int a);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    simpleDLL sdll = simpleDLL.INSTANCE;

    String result = sdll.giveCharGetChar("abc");
    System.out.println("result: " + result);

    int a = 3;
    int result1 = sdll.giveIntGetInt(a);  // calling function with int parameter&result
    System.out.println("giveIntGetInt("+a+"): " + result1);
    }
}
```

Here is my C++ code.

```
#include "simpleDLL.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
using std::string;


namespace simpleDLLNS
{
    string simpleDLL::giveCharGetChar(string a)
{
    return "abc";
}

int simpleDLL::giveIntGetInt(int a)
{
    return 3*a;
}

void simpleDLL::simpleCall(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    return;
}

int simpleDLL::giveVoidPtrGetInt(void* param)
{
    if(param!=0)
    {
        int* x = (int*)param;
        return *x;

    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
 }
}
```

Other than that, if I change my String to char, it return me korean word. If I am using String, Java will hit error. Please help.

Comment: I believe that JNA has special utilities for helping convert C Strings to Java Strings. Have you looked this up?

Comment: Hi @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't know there is something like this cause I look up calling dll function return type string and the results are not interested.

Comment: Java Strings and C/C++ Strings are completely different animals, and you need to convert if you're going to use one as another. Also a char is a primitive while Strings are references, another major difference.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I converted everything from String to char in both C++ and Java and I get korean word.

Comment: I know that JNI is not exactly the same this as JNA, but take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-010/ maybe this will give you some advice.

Answer (score 0):

See this example on how to send strings to a C library and receive strings from a C library using JNA from Java:

http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/index.html?example=2